# Cancelar efecto jquery a partir de 550px

Tags: html, jquery, css

Estoy usado el siguiente código para que 3 contenedores tenga la altura de el mas largo:

```
var maxHeight = 0;

$(".liste").each(function(){
    if ($(this).height() > maxHeight) { maxHeight = $(this).height(); }
});

$(".liste").height(maxHeight);
```

El problema es que necesito que caundo llegue a 550px, este pase otra vez a la altura original, es decir, deshabilitar el código. 
Intente esto:

```
var resizeTimer;
$(window).on('resize', function (e) {
    clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
    resizeTimer = setTimeout(function () {
        if ($(window).width() > 550) {
            $(".liste").height('auto');
        }
    }, 250);
});
```

Pero no va, alguien me podria ayudar?
Gracias

Comment: Creo que esto lo puedes hacer utilizando CSS flexbox. Pero si necesitas utilizar jQuery para esto: este articulo (en ingles) te puede ayudar: https://www.fourfront.us/blog/jquery-window-width-and-media-queries Lo que dice este articulo es: utilizar jQuery para comprobar si una propiedad CSS ha cambiado

Comment: Dios, pero que ciego soy, si metiendole un @media 550px height auto sobraba.....Gracias por el articulo

Comment: Agreguenlo como respuesta